# How do I view *.info document files on macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew

Is there a Homebrew package (or other source) that installs a macOS (Ventura 13.3.1) version of `info`?

Comment: Please add which macOS version you are using..

Comment: To answer the question in the title rather than in the body, emacs has an info-reader built into it: type `ctrl-H i`. As far as I can tell, that includes by default the info files in `$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/share/info`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, brew supplies the `texinfo` package, so named for the official GNU project. The same package name is common across many of the popular packaging systems for macOS and Linux alike. (Other Un*xes are available ;-)

`brew search info` would have revealed it to you.

The brew version is the only one on my Ventura machine. Ventura doesn't ship `/usr/bin/info` it seems.  Nothing in `/usr/share/info` either. This is probably due to `texinfo` now being licensed under GPL-3, though as always IANAL.

Further research based on https://opensource.apple.com/releases/ shows indeed that `texinfo` disappears between the release of macOS 12.5 and 13.0

Answer (score 0):

macOS ships `/usr/bin/info`, along with the info files in `/usr/share/info` that go with the few GPL2 utilities Apple still ships.

At least as late as Monterey, it does.  I do not have Ventura installed anywhere to be able to check if these are still included there.

Comment: Ventura doesn't ship /usr/bin/info it seems. The brew version is the only one on my Ventura machine. Nothing in `/usr/share/info` either.

Comment: Hmm, texinfo now appears to be GPL-3. Not sure when that changed, but surely a contributing factor to the discussion. https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/texinfo